# Google Map Auto-complete not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm facing a really peculiar issue here. I'm able to run a code on JsFiddle, but not able to run the exact code on Codepen.
Neither am i able to run it on my local.
Please fin below the links-

[CodePen Link](http://codepen.io/shaikmaqsood/pen/BQYppd)

[JsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/Shaikmaqsood/toxjg499/3/)

JavaScript Used-

```
var placeSearch, autocomplete;


function initAutocomplete() {
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
      {types: ['geocode']});

  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Your key isn't authorized for CodePen: `Google Maps API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error
Your site URL to be authorized: http://s.codepen.io/boomerang/ee5c28f48760ef39f4ce481d5c7ac3ff1480776136374/index.html`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If open the browser console you will notice the following error occurs on `codepen` site:

`RefererNotAllowedMapError exception`

Accordintg to [Error Messages page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages):

> The current URL loading the Google Maps JavaScript API has not been
>   added to the list of allowed referrers. Please check the referrer
>   settings of your API key on the Google API Console.
>
> See [API keys in the Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/apiui/credential). For more information, see [Best
>   practices for securely using API keys](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6310037).

To fix the issue:

- go to [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com)
- under `Credentials` menu select select appropriate API key
- in the list of HTTP referers add `http://s.codepen.io/*`

[image]